# Get all json data from web in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

Hello I am trying to get all json data from this page:

https://www.espn.com/soccer/team/_/id/4438&xhr=1

But in response.body only contains part off json

I get data here:

```
    Future<NextPartido> getPartidoHome() async {
  var response = await http.get(baseUrl);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var body = json.decode(response.body);
    print(body);
    // JsonEncoder encoder = new JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
    // String prettyprint = encoder.convert(body);
    // log('movieTitle: $prettyprint');
    //
    return NextPartido.fromJson(body);
  } else {
    return throw Exception('Error getting partidohome');
  }
}
```

I have model class generate here:
https://app.quicktype.io/

Is posible that response.body not contains all json data??

And how I can get all json in response?

Answer (score 0):

```
  If you want to have all data your model should be like this : 

  => https:// paste.of code.org / Vt6YciMmTLkirmjVYYc6Sd

  Your method could be like this :

  => Future<TestModel> getAllData() async {
  var result;
  var request = await http.get(baseUrl);

  if(request.statusCode == 200) {
    result =  testModelFromJson(request.body.toString());
  } else {
    print(request.statusCode.toString());
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I can't get all the json, I still have the same problem and I only get from the value ads, which is halfway through the json more or less